# Find optimal balance of memory_limit and (upload_max_filesize & post_max_size)

Tags: php, memory, file-upload

I am uploading files and having trouble finding an answer to this question. Some of the time my file upload fails at `move_uploaded_file()` so I was told this could be a memory problem. Unfortunately there is no documentation available that I could find to answer this question.

The file I am uploading is 400mb and I set `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to 500mb. The `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` are set to 60000 for testing purposes. My `memory_limit` is set to default 128mb. Should this be changed? **How can you calculate the optimal balance of `memory_limit` vs `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` for say a 400mb file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the upload fails, you shouldn't even be attempting to do a move_uploaded_file. The proper bare-bones upload handling method is

```
if ($_FILES['yourfile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   ... upload failed, bail out
   die("Failed upload");
}
// got here, upload must've worked
move_uploaded_file(...);
```

The error codes are [detailed here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), and will tell you if the file was too large to handle due to PHP settings.

As for the PHP settings themselves. Your `post_max_size` should be the largest allowable file size, plus whatever other data you're submitting alongside the file upload. memory_limit must be larger than the max file size, plus extra to allow for script overhead. PHP's execution time limits do not come into play for uploads, as the script timers are not started until AFTER the upload is completed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Marc, I will track these settings and pay attention to errors. However, don't you think setting memory_limit to  400mb+ could be overkill or even dangerous (could server overload)? Does it really take that much memory to upload a file? I have 3 gb ram. Does that mean only 7 people can upload a 400mb file at a time (3000/400)?

Comment: PHP's file upload capabilities are pretty crappy compared to other languages. I've never tried doing enough uploads to try and exceed the physical memory in a server, but in theory, yes, only 7 people could upload.

Comment: Alright thanks Marc, you have been quite helpful. Just one more question, does max_execution_time time start when the file upload starts or when the php processing script initiates. I feel like setting it to 60000 is a little dangerous.